# Formatting Windows Command Line Call For Executing R Script from Python

Tags: python

This is similar to a number of questions, but could still use some clarity. My example is still unable to run, so I may be missing something.

I'm trying to run a full R script from Python. I don't need to see it, or get output, but need it to run and preferably know when it's completed.
I am using Python 3.7.0 (Run from Spyder), R 3.5.2, and Windows 10.

I can run this from Windows Command Line with:

```
Rscript test_script.R
```

When I'm in the location with the script, or if I'm not in that location:

```
Rscript C:/Path/to/test_script.R
```

From Python I tried:

```
import subprocess
command = 'Rscript'
script = 'C:/Path/to/test_script.R'
subprocess.Popen([command,script], shell=True)
```

This does not give an error, but I can see from the directories where the Rscript would create files, that nothing has run (And it would take awhile to run). In the Python console, the 'output' displays '1'

I have also tried:

```
import subprocess
command = 'C:/Path/to/Rscript.exe --vanilla -q -f C:/Path/to/test_script.R'
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

I'm not sure what the `--Vannilla -q -f` means, but I saw it used often in other questions.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong or how to get this to execute?

Comment: If you're on the windows command line, your command is going to need to use windows syntax (using `-` for flags is unix syntax, windows usually uses backslashes). What's the command you would use to run the thing on the command line? Literally just put that into popen and see what happens

Comment: Good to know. If you look at the first two code snippets, that what I run on windows command line (and it works). The first of the two Python snippets should still be formatted for Windows based on what you said. Just putting the command into Popen returns '2' (or is I add 'shell=True' it returns '1').